# ¿Por que hibernate crea la columna id cuando especifico otra clave primaria?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Estoy trabajando en [openxava](/questions/tagged/openxava), un framework basado en `Java`, y al utilizar `Hibernate` me **crea** una columna llamada **id** en base de datos (`MySql`), aún cuando específico en la clase que **la clave primaría** se llama **login**.
Pongo el código:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "categoria")
public class Categoria {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "login", unique=true, table = "categoria")
    private String login;
    @Column(name = "categoria", table = "categoria")
    private String categoria;
    @Column(name = "servicio", table = "categoria")
    private String servicio;
    @Column(name = "correo", table = "categoria")
    private String correo;
    // Getters and Setters...
}
```

¿Estoy definiendo algo mal?
¿Cual podria ser la causa?
Gracias por la ayuda, estoy atento por si necesitais algo mas.

Comment: Creo que es porque el id debería ser un numero (Long por ejemplo) en vez de un String y aparte se no se debería de dar mas propiedades al campo que vallas a usar de @ID, prueba a usar un long de id

Comment: Entiendo, pero no hay alguna forma de que sea un tipo String, ¿Si lo marco como unico no vale?
Es que ya es una base de datos hecha donde la clave primaria es del tipo String.

Comment: Si lo marcas como unico, solo servirá para que no se repita, el usar un numero como id es una convención que siguen la mayoría de bases de datos relacionales mas que nada para indexar mejor las datos a la hora de las busquedas pero igualmente prueba a quitar toda la linea que va debajo de @id (La segunda notacion sobraría osea todo lo que es la línea de @column) a ver si así te deja usar un String como id (aunque no es muy aconsejable)

Comment: al poner ´@Table(name = "categoria")´ esto ya no va en los column ´, table = "categoria"´ y el problema es que le estas poniendo ´, unique=true' a la columna. Por defecto ´@Id´ ya es ´unique´ y ´not null´ por eso cuando le vuelves a poner ´unique=true´ te crea la nueva columna.

Comment: He realizado los cambios que me decis, y me sigue creando la columna por defecto... :(

Comment: Comprobe mal, funciona corrrectamente, muchas gracias. 
Los consejos, los tendre presentes en otras clases tambien.
Gracias por vuestra ayuda